# protocol buffers with C++ client and C# back-end?

Tags: c#, c++, protocol-buffers

How do you connect C# back-end with a C++ front-end via HTTP or web-service equivalent?

Comment: Why protocol buffers specifically? I'm heavily involved in that area, but I just want to sense-check your reasoning...

Comment: I'm doing MFC/C++ project with back-end C#. Need some way to talk between C# and C++ over HTTP

Comment: OK; why not just SOAP...? I'm asking to make sure that we don't lead you down the wrong path. Sure, protobuf *can* help in this setup, especially if you are constrained by bandwidth or CPU, but for many scenarios SOAP may be simpler.

Comment: Because all C++ soap implementations are pay-ware...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three parts here; the server (sounds like C#), the client (sounds like C++) and the transport. Taking them separately, and starting with the most important:

- the transport: big decision here is what shape you want the data to be in. You mention protocol buffers, so we're talking binary - but that could be:

  - a raw octet-stream (think: downloading an image from a web-server)
  - a SOAP web-service returning a stream or byte[]
  - the same SOAP web-service returning MTOM

  Any should work; which to choose depends on the tools available. The important thing is : get a chunk of binary over the wire.

  You also need to think about the data definition at this point; a [.proto file](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/proto.html) can define your schema, and most protocol buffers implementations include a tool to generate matching classes.
- the server: depending on the choice above, this is either going to be a handler (`IHttpHandler`) or a web-service class. Either way, their job is really to run some logic and return a byte stream. How you get your data is up to you, then ultimately the job is to 
  populate the DTO types (generated from .proto in many cases, but not *strictly* necessary) and run it through the serialization API, writing the result to the stream
- the client: same in reverse; generate your DTOs from the .proto, and run it through the deserialization API

The various protobuf implementations (C++, C#, etc) are listed [here](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/wiki/ThirdPartyAddOns).

Comment: I saw all of them. Do you accept paypal to write an open-source example which demonstrates using C++ and C# together in web-service?

Comment: @buttercup - I'm genuinely not good enough at C++ to help with that. I can show you getting protobuf data on the wire from C#, *sure*. Then it should just be a case of deconstructing that from C++. There is (IIRC) plenty of C++ documentation, or maybe posting to the specific group might help: http://groups.google.com/group/protobuf

Comment: @buttercup - based on your "pay-ware" point about avoiding SOAP, I'd also suggest that raw octet-stream is the way to go in this case.

Comment: next related question: how do you start HTTP transport from MFC/C++ ?

Comment: And to repeat; I can't advise on that. I'm not a C++ expert, sorry.

Comment: I'll split, can you write the server-side example, and someone else writes the C++ client example?

Comment: Answer for C# side is here:
http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2010/06/extending-aspnet-mvc-with-custom.html

Answer (score 0):

The C++ accesses the exposed parts of the back-end via HTTP-Requests in which form you choose (webservice and others).

Comment: Do you have an example, or more complete example? I could not find one.

Comment: Do you have example of back-end C#, or at least how it should be.