# How to do HTTP transfers with MFC/C++?

Tags: c++, mfc

How do you do HTTP transfers in MFC?

Which library would you use to access HTTP resources in MFC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [MFC wrappers](http://www.dotnetheaven.com/Uploadfile/mahesh/WinInetMFCClasses05242005085341AM/WinInetMFCClasses.aspx) for the [WinInet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385483.aspx) library.

Comment: Related question to this. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040140/protocol-buffers-with-c-client-and-c-back-end

How do you connect the two together?

Comment: that is, connect Protocol Buffers with WinInet and with C# back-end Protocol Buffer.net

Answer (score 0):

Here are three possible ways:

1. Write the socket code yourself.
2. Use the libcurl library.
3. Use the C++ abstraction for libcurl called cURLpp.